# Triggering specific class from .jar file for cron job?

Tags: java, bash, amazon-web-services, jar, cron

I am running an AWS EC2 Linux instance, on which I uploaded a .jar file of a piece of software that I wrote.
In order to trigger the app periodically, I want to use cron - and setup crontab in the following way:

```
23 12 * * * java -jar  /home/ec2-user/Cube-Core/Cube.jar > /home/ec2-user/CubeCore/CronLogfiles/test.log 2>&1
```

The paths all match, and I redirected the sysout and syserr from the software to a testlog file.

However: when cron does the job, what does he trigger within the jar itself? is he looking for a class called 'main' (that is just my assumption, since I am new to cron). If this is the case, how can I tell him explicitly which class to trigger, since my project's main class is called differently?

Also, I read only that some guys prefer to trigger a bash script with cron, and have the script itself trigger the .jar execution. I, on other hand, am telling crontab directly to execute the .jar. Which of these 2 ways is the 'cleanest' and why, or is it in the end just a matter of not overclutting the crontab entries?

Thank you all ,

Cheers

Comment: Are you able to execute your program using jar file from command line ?

Comment: `cron` just calls `java`. It is `java` that loads and executes the `jar` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) indicate you need to define the entry point in the manifest:

```
Main-Class: classname
```

Depending on what you use to create your jar, there may be some configuration convenience to do that.

Good for you: you don't have to do anything special about the cron job. 
Not so good for you: it's done upon creating the jar, so if it's not there, that's quite a hassle.

But tbh, I'd suppose that if the jar works normally, there shouldn't be anything extra to do.

Comment: that was it. thank you! I used Gradle to build the jar, and forgot to sepcify the mainClassName and was missing a plugin as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Jar with single Main class**

```
java -jar myjar.jar`
```

It will get the main class details from your meta file within your jar,

```
Main-class : com.yourpackage.Mainclass
```

**2. Jar with more than one main class** 
If you have more than one main class in your single jar then you can go with the below format,

```
java -cp myjar.jar MyClass
```